# How to find latest inserted row from db row in YII?

Tags: lastinsertid, yii

I have a table "backup_history" which store sites backup details in my database with the following fields:

```
id
site_id
backup_file_name
file_size
by (cron/manual)
datetime
```

For the next backup, I need to find out recent last backup date n time of the site and compare with the settings(daily backup) and run next backup by cron.

But am unable to find out last inserted row with the
 **site_id = $id AND by = 'cron' AND datetime = 'this will be recent date-time'**

```
$lastbackup = BackupHistory::model()->findByAttributes(array('site_id' => $single_site->id, 'by' => 'cron'));
```

This code provides a row but not with recent date n time.
May be am going wrong so plz suggest some solution. Thanks !!!

Comment: yes `order by` makes sense, didn't see your comment..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to [`order by`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#order-detail) your result. So try this:

```
$lastbackup = BackupHistory::model()->findByAttributes(array('site_id' => $single_site->id, 'by' => 'cron'),array('order'=>'datetime'));
```